# user login in vb.net Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I'm sorry for disturbing you guys, but I had a question to ask. I'm currently doing a program where user which are in the access database can log in, the code is working but the problem is that when I debug I can only login using 1 user, when I try logging in using another user account it shows Login Invalid and I'm not sure why. I hope someone could pin point what am I doing wrong;
Here's my code;

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb 'provides classes to connect to the database
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO

Public Class Login
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

Function getcount() As Integer
    Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection _
("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\User.mdb")
        'provider to be used when working with access database
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM UserProf_table", conn)
        Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    End Using
End Function

Private Sub Login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn = New OleDbConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & Application.StartupPath & "\User.mdb"
    conn.Open()

    If getcount() = 1 Then
        btnReg.Visible = False
    Else
        btnReg.Visible = True
    End If
    MsgBox(conn.State.ToString()) 'to check connection 
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim idbx As String ' noted that ID is numbers
    Dim pwd As String

    idbx = idbox.Text
    pwd = pwdbox.Text
    With cmd
        'Open Connection for executereader
        If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        'initialized database connection
        .Connection = conn

        .CommandText = "SELECT UserID, UserPwd FROM UserProf_table WHERE UserID = '" & idbox.Text & "' AND UserPwd = '" & pwdbox.Text & "'"

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            If idbx = dr.Item("UserID") And pwd = dr.Item("UserPwd") Then
                idbx = SystemInformation.UserName
                mainForm.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                MsgBox("Password or username is incorrect")
                idbox.Clear()
                pwdbox.Clear()
            End If
            dr.Close()

        End If
    End With
    'close connection
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReg_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReg.Click
    registerForm.Show() ' Register form
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
End Class
```

Here's my database:
[image]

I login using the UserID and UserPwd. And is there a way for me to save the UserID do that I can use it in different form? Thank you in advance

Comment: please do not edit your question's code in place. it invalidates existing answers and makes it hard for visitors to understand .

Answer (score 0):

You are always reading the whole username/password list!
You have forgotten a `WHERE` clause in :

```
SELECT UserID, UserPwd FROM UserProf_table

WHERE UserId = ???
```

You can login as the first user because it's the first row returned!

**[Also: please don't store passwords as plain text]**

Comment: i changed it now to "SELECT UserID,UserPwd FROM UserProf_table WHERE UserID = '" & idbox.Text & "' AND UserPwd = '" & pwdbox.Text & "'" but there's an error in (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader)

Answer (score -1):

You should change your sql command to retrieve only 1 record:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT UserID,UserPwd FROM UserProf_table WHERE UserId =" + idbx.trim()
```

Moreover, if you are using Visual Studio, you can use "Watch and QuickWatch Windows" in debug mode to show your variables and make sure they return expected values.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx